# Moving from PDF to EPUB for already published ebook

Tags: self-publishing, kindle, amazon

I made the mistake to follow the advice of the kindle Create desktop app to use the PDF format for creating my cookbook. Now I realise that older models of the kindle will not be able to display this and want to change it to an EPUB format.

When trying to reupload the document as EPUB I get an error message saying it is not possible to change an existing publication going from static to flowing layout, but I need to do exactly that.

What is the most straightforward solution for this? Do I really have to delete the publication and reupload it in the EPUB format? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, PDF is supported by more early Kindles than EPUB.

[image]

Specifically, the Kindle 2 and Kindle 3 support PDF but not EPUB. (I'm not sure how many of each device are still in use.)

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#Supporting_platforms